# How to implement a nested java interface in scala

Tags: java, scala

Say I have the following legacy java defined:

```
abstract class A {

  abstract I foo();

  public interface I
  {
    int bar();
  }
}
```

And I want to implement this in scala something like the following:

```
class MyA extends A {

  def foo() = new I {

    def bar = 3

  }
}
```

The scala will not compile with the error

> not found: type I

How can I refer to the java interface I in my scala code?

Comment: Have you tried `new A.I`?

Comment: Have you tried `A.I`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
class MyA extends A {
  def foo() = new A.I {
    def bar = 3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your java code through scala-colored lenses, you'll see

- a class `A` with an abstract method `foo`,
- an object `A` with a single interface in it, `A.I`.

Since the companion's members [are not auto-imported inside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727887/738138), you'll need to use `A.I` or import it first:

```
def foo() = new A.I { ... }

// or with an import
import A.I
def foo() = new I { ... }
```