# Allow underscore imports of companion object's items in Scalastyle

Tags: scalastyle

I'd like to make scalastyle to ignore underscore imports in case when it is companion object's fields that are being imported(it makes sense to me):

```
class Item {
  import Item._ //scalastyle marks it as a warning

}

object Item {
  case object Nested
  def someMethod(): Unit = {..}
}
```

UnderscoreImportChecker is responsible for this inspection, but it has no configuration parameters

```
<check level="warning" class="org.scalastyle.scalariform.UnderscoreImportChecker" enabled="true"></check>
```

Here is the similar question:
[Companion class requires import of Companion object methods and nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704769/companion-class-requires-import-of-companion-object-methods-and-nested-objects)

I'd like to ask if there is a way to write a custom Checker(I'll try to investigate it)?

P.S. I'm aware that I can use //scalastyle:off or explicit imports but it would be repetitive and inconvenient to use.